# Save Converted PDF Directly to Server not in Device memory

Tags: android, pdf

I want to save my file directly into the server and not into my device. currently, the converted PDF file is being saved into my phone's storage. how do i get it to send that file into the server directly?

the path that i want to save the file to is:

```
"http://"+IP+"/OMAS/docs/"
```

my code that contains the path that saves into the internal storage:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDFfiles/");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }

        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDFfiles/";
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDFfiles/");

        path = path + filename + ".pdf";
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 38, 38, 50, 38);
        Rectangle documentRect = document.getPageSize();


        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(path));
```

Comment: just hit the Web api to upload the file and after success delete the file from storage

Comment: that is my second option. i want to know if is it possible to directly upload it to the server or nah?

Comment: use cache memory to store temporary and it will be only accessible to app

Comment: your app* only .